# Which google api should I use?(maps)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making website that lists places on google maps(added by users) which api shuld I use to achieve it?

Is there anything for that or should I just load locations from my database and mark them on map on every reload?

Comment: You should store the coordinates of the locations in your database and use that data (and the Maps API) to show the locations on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need a database to store the coordinates of locations added by your users and fetch and display them as per need on the map. The [Google Maps Apiv3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) is suitable for this.

To reduce burden from fetching the coordinates from the database every time on reload, you can use the concept of [Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which would fairly help to improve the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

For mapping you should use the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics), see the [Articles](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/) section of the documentation for ideas on interfacing with a database.